# How effectively we can code null checks Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Little **new to Java 8 style**;

How effectively, we can code for the below statement by including all the null checks usin Java 8 API

```
search.getResource()
                        .getResults().get(0).getCustomer().getPhoneNumber()
```

I tried like following: ***(Looks little weird to me with Optional everywhere)***

```
List<Result> results = search.getResource().getResults();

                Optional<Result> optionalResult =  Optional.of(results).orElse(new ArrayList<>()).stream().findFirst();
                if(optionalResult.isPresent() && Optional.of(optionalResult.get().getCustomer()).isPresent()) {
                    Source source = Optional.of(optionalResult.get().getCustomer()).get();
                    Optional<List<Customer>> customers = Optional.of(source.getCustomers());
                    if(customers.isPresent() && customers.get().stream().findFirst().isPresent() &&
                            Optional.of(customers.get().stream().findFirst().get().getPhoneNumber()).isPresent())
                        dest.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(customers.get().stream().findFirst().get().getPhoneNumber())));
                }
```

Could you please suggest me a better way of doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`map` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) of `Optional` class:

```java
final Optional<String> optional = Optional.ofNullable(search.getResource())
    .map(resource -> resource.getResults())
    .map(results -> results.size() > 0 ? results.get(0) : null)
    .map(result -> result.getCustomer())
    .map(customer -> customer.getPhoneNumber());

optional.ifPresent(phoneNumber -> {
    System.out.println(phoneNumber);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply;   .map(resource -> resource.getResults())
    .map(results -> results.size() > 0 ? results.get(0) : null)  results null check do we need here?

Comment: I mean; what if resource.getResults() is null

Comment: The `map` docs states: "If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it. [...] Otherwise return an empty Optional." So if `resource.getResults()` is null, none of the `map`s preceded by it will be executed.

Comment: This pipeline would be clearer to read with method references; everything except the `results` check can have the lambda removed.

Comment: Thanks @enzo got it.

Comment: @RamKowsu Glad to help! If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2):

**OT:** Why don't you simply code *null safe*?

Coding *null safe* means that you **never** explicitly retun a (literal) `null` from a method or pass one in as a parameter. Furthermore you **always** do you `null` checks on local variables **before** you pass them around or return them.
On `Map` collections you use  `getOrDefault` or `computeIfAbsent` to replace the `null` returned for missing keys with a *Null Equivalent Constant* of the expected type.

Usually passing `null` back and forth is a *in band signal for an error condition* which Java has *exceptions* for.

And no: passing around `Optional` is not a solution, but another incarnation of the problem. `Optional` is an elegant way to deal with variables than may contain `null` **within** a method.
Don't let it escape...

Comment: that makes sense, will try that

Comment: @RamKowsu It's a "Yoda thing" *Do, or do not. There is no try.* ;o)